# about comparing two strings in java and expluding repeats

Tags: java, search

OK lets say the secret pin is:

> 2236 (resident evil 2 reference)

if a person type 2200
I get a match count of 2;

But:

If the person type: 2000 or 0200, or 0020, or 0002
results says that it still matches 2 numbers.

It should only match one of the 2 number but I still get a match count of 2.

I'm currently using :

`if(currentPin.indexOf(secretPin.charAt(i)) != -1)`

on a loop.

UPDATE:

Assuming all the the necessary variables are declared and initialized and all scopes are closed

heres the code that does the matching

`for (int i = 0; i < secretPin.length(); i++) 
    {
        if (currentPin.indexOf(secretPin.charAt(i)) != -1) 
        {
            System.out.println("Found");
            match++;
        }
    }`

//output: 
2236 //SECRET NUMBER display 
0002 //USER GUESS 
Found 
Found 
MATCH: 2 // should only match 1 if USER GUESS only contain one number 2

Comment: did you mean excluding by saying expulding? and it is not clear at all what your question is?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @SashaSalauyou sorry... the question is how can I get a matchCount = 1; when the user only type one of the duplicate number... meaning that if the user lets say only typed 2000 compared with 2236, then only count one of the 2 to match

Comment: @KickButtowski yea... i meant excluding.. (long day)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the number of digits is always the same between secret pin and current pin, this simple algorithm would do the trick to retrieve the number of match :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String secretPin = "2236";
    String currentPin = "6322";

    int match = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < currentPin.length(); i++) {
        if (secretPin.contains(String.valueOf(currentPin.charAt(i)))) {
            secretPin = secretPin.replaceFirst(String.valueOf(currentPin.charAt(i)), "");
            match++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(match);

}
```

Comment: yes but lets say the secretPin is 2236 meaning that there are two 2s BUT the currentPin has 2000. it should only say 1 match found since the current number is contains only one 2.

Comment: no i wanted the match = 1. because secretPin is 2236 and currentPin is 2000. in the currentPin there is only "one 2" but the secretPin has "two 2s" i want the user to actually type lets say 2020 to get a match = 2... if the user type 0020 or 0002 or 0200 it should only say match = 1

Comment: I'd like to say thank you for fast reply and being patient.. however what i meant was the user can type the 2 "anywhere" in the four digit and still get a match count. 2000, 0200, 0020, 0002 should say match = 1;.. my code was originally written as you suggest..

Comment: sorry again if it wasnt clear and thank you for really looking it to is as i am... i was testing it and i thought it was solved BUT then i typed 0200 it says match = 2; :-( nothing should be replaced and user must type 4 digits. lets say the person typed 0322, there should be match =3; if the user type 6322, match should be 4

Comment: this PLUS some modifications finally solved it... at first when it reloops i notice that it changed the secretPin value... so basically i added a line that redefines the secretPin back to its original state before looping again +1

Answer (score 0):

"if(currentPin.indexOf(secretPin.charAt(i) != -1)" is getting a character, checks if it's != -1, and passes the boolean result to indexOf.  You also have a bracket mismatch.  As given this will not compile, let alone produce inaccurate output.  Please paste the code you say you are able to run if you would like it reviewed.

Comment: lets assume all code works, =) the secret pin is 2236 and the user put 0020. it should only say that I found one 2 but this code says that I found two 2 (which is incorrect) i know whats happening in my code... but i am having trouble how to only match 1 compare when the secret pin contains duplicate/or  multiple of the same number